# How to check if value of one column is in another column of another row

Tags: sql

I have the following table "myTable":

```
ID    | Name   | Parent | Memo
________________________________________
1     | Obj1   | 1      | server object
2     | Obj2   | 1      | local object
3     | Obj3   | 2      | server object
4     | Obj4   | 3      | local object
```

and I want all IDs of objects that are never used in the parent column and where memo = local object.
So in this example it would be row 4, cause there isn't any row in this table with parent = 4 and its memo = local object.

What would be a good sql statement for that case?

Mine looks like this:

```
select ID from db.myTable t1 where t1.memo = 'local object' and not exists
(select * from db.myTable t2 where t2.parent = t1.ID)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But there has to be a more efficient way than using 2 select statements

Comment: your subquery select looks fine ... you could replace that with a join ... what size of tables are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine:

```
select ID
from db.myTable t1
where t1.memo = 'local object' and
      not exists (select 1 from db.myTable t2 where t2.parent = t1.ID);
```

For performance, you want indexes on `mytable(memo, id)` and `mytable(parent)`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do a left outer join for these types of statements, combined with a filter, something like this;

```
select ID 
  from db.myTable t1 
  left join db.myTable t2
    on t2.parent = t1.ID
 where t1.memo = 'local object' 
   and t2.parent is null -- arbitrary none nullable column
```

Not sure if it's more efficient, but it looks nicer (IMHO).

Comment: No offence, just to communicate a fact, it is not more efficient, on SQL server the execution plans are the same for both queries.